# libvirt user access stopped working

Tags: permissions, kvm, qemu, libvirt

I'm using `virsh` and `virt-manager` to manage some qemu/kvm VMs on an otherwise vanilla CentOS machine.

Our admins' user accounts are given the `libvirt` group. This had worked for a long time, but suddenly stopped. For some time now, access without root privileges has been broken. Running as user:

```
$ virsh -c qemu:///system list --all
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: Fehler vom Service: CheckAuthorization: Failed to open file “/proc/2020139/status”: No such file or directory
```

I have checked the `libvirtd.conf`, which looks normal. I can see `/var/run/libvirt` populated as expected.

SELinux is enabled, but no entries in audit log and `setenforce 0` did not change anything either.

Answer (score 0):

So this is related to polkit not being able to access other processes' data due to `hidepid=2` option in `/proc` mount options, as polkit doesn't have root privileges.

There are two possible solutions: 1) use `hidepid=0` on the proc file system's mount options in `/etc/fstab`, 2) Verify your polkit runs with group `polkitd`, then keep the hidepid option and add `gid=polkitd` to those options instead. This allows users in polkitd group to ignore the hidepid setting.